# Using an Excel sheet or .csv file to automatically update form information in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I would like to populate form fields in a pdf automatically by reading from an excel sheet.

For example, if I have a field in a pdf document called "Address", and I have an excel sheet in the same folder with a cell containing the "Address", I would like the field in the pdf to automatically update if someone changes the address cell in the excel sheet.

I am aware that you can import an excel sheet into Acrobat Pro manually, but I would like this to happen automatically when the document opens.

I have been looking into using Acrobat's javascript, but am unable to get a sense of how to use it for this application.

If I haven't made myself clear, please feel free to ask and I will try clarify.

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

In Excel I would set up a cell onChange event for the cell which contain the address. If the cell value changes you can call acrobat and fill the form with the new value. Attached the vbs/vba subroutine code you need in xls to fill the form in a pdf.

Help and background info you will find in the Adobe Acrobat SDK, IAC section. Good luck, Reinhard

```
fileIn = "D:\Test2.pdf"              '// state the full path of the file to open
xlsCellValue = "newAddress"        '// value you want to set

Set App = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")     '// start Adobe Acrobat
App.Show                           '// show Acrobat or comment out for hidden mode

Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc") '// connect to Ac Viewer
if AVDoc.Open(fileIn,"") then              '// Open a file into viewer
    Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc             '// Get the Doc opened in the viewer
    set jso = PDDoc.GetJSObject            '// Connect to Acrobat JS
    set xf = jso.getField("Address")        '// get field object
    xf.value = xlsCellValue             '// set field value
    jso.app.alert(xf.value)         '// Display new value in a MsgBox
    PDDoc.save 1, fileIn            '//save the file
end if

App.CloseAllDocs                  '// close active documents
App.exit
```